# .NET Sqlite SQL Shell?

Tags: .net, sql, sqlite, shell

I'm using the [official SQLite for .NET](http://system.data.sqlite.org/) but I would like to use it as a SQL shell (like the sqlite command-line shell), where users can enter arbitrary SQL, such as:

```
>>> CREATE TABLE employee (firstname varchar(32), lastname varchar(32))
>>> insert into employee values('First','Last');
>>> select * from employee;
First | Last
```

and maybe even:

```
>>> .tables
employee
```

Is there code in the library to make this easy? Or another library to wrap SQLite for .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sqlite3` command-line tool is implemented in the file [`shell.c`](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/finfo?name=src/shell.c), using the SQLite C API.

System.Data.SQLite offers everything from that API (except for [`sqlite3_complete()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/complete.html)), so if you want to build your own shell on top of .NET, you have to port everything in that file to some .NET language.

Comment: No. What would be the point of duplicating the `sqlite3` tool?

Comment: To have a managed version which is platform independent and can be integrated with other .NET languages.

Comment: The `sqlite3` tool as it exists now alread _is_ platform independent; it's available on all .NET platforms, and more. To integrate with .NET languages, you wouldn't need as much a command-line tool as an object-based API.

Comment: Yes, we could call into the binary C-based sqlite3 command-line on all platforms, but we don't want to do that. We want to work with it as a managed .NET library, but with all of that functionality in some form of the sqlite3 command-line tool.

Comment: Looks like there is a port of shell.c into C# for a different Sqlite library: http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/source/browse/Community.CsharpSqlite.shell/src/shell.cs

Comment: Another version of same, with some updates: https://code.google.com/r/wwahammy-csharp-sqlite/source/browse/#hg%2FCommunity.CsharpSqlite.shell%2Fsrc